# Making a Django Profile-change Form Autofill

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I have written a model for a custom user and views that allow me to add new users, see their profile info, and login/out.
However, whilst writing a view for my users to update their profile information, I discovered that the form that was being displayed required the user to fill in all their details again, even if they didn't want to change that specific detail. For example, if a user wanted to just change their last name, they'd have to enter their email, password, first name etc all over again.
Is there a way for me to have this form autofilled, and a user can just change what they require?
I have attached my forms and views code below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def personal(request):
    """
    Personal data of the user profile
    """
    profile = MyUser.get_full_name #This returns the email address

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _("Your profile information has been updated successfully."))

    else:
        form = ProfileForm

    template = "update_profile.html"
    data = { 'section': 'personal', 'form': form, }
    return render_to_response(template, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Profile Form. Composed by all the Profile model fields.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        exclude = ('is_active', 'is_admin', 'last_login')
```

**Error After Implementing Solution**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/friends/update/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.7
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'friends')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Uni\_Project\friend_finder_V2\mysite\friends\views.py" in personal
  85.         form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __init__
  315.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in model_to_dict
  124.     opts = instance._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /friends/update/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instance` kwarg to pass the current profile to your form also on GET (I see that you already passing it on POST). Also, don't forget to do an HTTP redirect after making a change to your database with POST. Something like this:

```
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
if request.method == 'POST:
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, _("Your profile information has been updated successfully."))
        # TODO You need to do a redirect here
else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

Comment: After giving this a go, I am getting an error saying: "'function' object has no attribute '_meta'". Any idea about solving this one?

Comment: Please update your original message with the full stacktrace. It seems that django expects an object and you are passing a function...

Comment: Have updated now, the problem seems to arise from the: profile = MyUser.get_full_name line I think.